# Jest - import a node module

Tags: angular, npm, jestjs, prismjs

I have an Angular component that imports a node module (in this case it's prismjs).

```
import Prism from 'prismjs';
import 'prismjs/components/prism-markup';
...
```

I have a piece of code that references `Prism.highlightElement()`

However, when I run my tests I get the error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'highlightElement' of undefined`

I assume that Jest is mocking the node_module, but any idea how to stop it.

I'm using the Angular Preset Jest library and I've tried:

`unmockedModulePathPatterns: ['./node_modules/prismjs']` in the config and it doesn't work.

I've also tried:
`unmockedModulePathPatterns: ['prismjs']`
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by changing my import statement to:

```
import * as Prism from 'prismjs';
```

I have no idea why this works.